# Crystal Report prompts for the same parameter twice

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using CR 2011. 
In my report, I used Command for my datasource. In the command I used parameters to restrict the amount of record read. A simplified version of the command is something like that: Select .. from ... where myDate is between {?Start} and {?Stop}.

The report worked correctly, only one annoying thing is the report asked for the dates to be entered twice. The dates were prompted when command was run and then prompted again along with other parameters.

Do we have a work around this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Adding command is one time job...once command is added tou will only run the report...I dont see any isssue here...to the far CR is concerned

Comment: You will get the parameter prompt when you edit or view the SQL Command and then each time you run the report. This is normal. If you're being prompted for start/stop dates twice when running the report, verify you haven't inadvertently added two sets of parameters (adding parameters in the SQL Command window are treated _separately_ from those added to the report normally).

Comment: @Ryan: Thank you for your comment. I got prompted every single time I run the report, not just when I edited it. I do see another set of Start, Stop in the parameters but I think they were carried over from the parameters in the Command. If this is not the case, please advised me how to remove them. I do not remember adding them. Normally, when right clicking at the parameter, one will have an option to delete. I do not see the option with Start and End parameters which makes me think they are from the Command. No other parameters asking for date time in the report.